# Macro - "Save As" original Workbook name

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, csv

Intended actions:

1. Copy & Paste columns CA:CF from 123.csv to 123a.csv

Could anyone please assist with the "SaveAs" original workbook name with the appended "a"?

Thanks.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'
    Columns("CA:CF").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ChDir "A:\test\Exported files"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "A:\test\Exported files\123.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please edit the code below:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "A:\test\Exported files\123.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
```

To:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "A:\test\Exported files\123a.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
```

Comment: LOL.  This did actually make me laugh.

I tried to keep the question brief, but clearly failed in my explanation.

I want the macro to "Save As" the original filename, with an appended "a", regardless of what the original file name is.

So it can be run against 20+ .csv files and I end with the same result each time.